# long - big numbers in map don't calc as should

Tags: android, variables, basic4android

i am using big numbers (18 digits), so i store it into long variables.
I have found some misbehavior in my calculations, hence i made a simple test program.

The calculation does not work as it should with big numbers...
More precise it is linked to the Map i use for storing.
Any suggestions?

```
    'Activity module
Sub Process_Globals
    'These global variables will be declared once when the application starts.
    'These variables can be accessed from all modules.

End Sub

Sub Globals
    'These global variables will be redeclared each time the activity is created.
    'These variables can only be accessed from this module.
    Dim b1,b2,b3 As Button
    Dim MapData As Map
End Sub

Sub Activity_Create(FirstTime As Boolean)
    b1.Initialize("Set100")
    b1.Text="Set100"
    Activity.AddView(b1,10%x,10%y,80%x,20%y)
    b2.Initialize("SetBig")
    b2.Text="SetBig"
    Activity.AddView(b2,10%x,40%y,80%x,20%y)
    b3.Initialize("Increase")
    b3.Text="long++"
    Activity.AddView(b3,10%x,70%y,80%x,20%y)
    MapData.Initialize
End Sub

Sub Activity_Resume

End Sub

Sub Activity_Pause (UserClosed As Boolean)

End Sub

Sub Set100_Click
    Dim l As Long
    l = 100
    Log("set to: " & l)
    MapData.Put("Token",l)
End Sub

Sub SetBig_Click
    ' long range: -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807
    Dim l As Long
    l = 640345893847300380
    Log("set to: " & l)
    MapData.Put("Token",l)
End Sub

Sub Increase_Click
    Dim l As Long
    l = MapData.Get("Token")
    Log("from map: " & l)
    l = l + 1
    Log("new val : " & l)
    MapData.Put("Token",l)
End Sub
```

Comment: What does it do that's different from what you expect?

Comment: If i read the value back, it is different to the stored value. stored 640345893847300380, read back 640345893847300352

Comment: it must have to do with the map object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. There is a bug in the conversion from an unknown object to Long which causes this error. This bug will be fixed in the next update.
In the meantime you can create a custom type and store it instead.

```
Sub Globals
    'These global variables will be redeclared each time the activity is created.
    'These variables can only be accessed from this module.
    Dim b1,b2,b3 As Button
    Dim MapData As Map
    Type MyLong(l As Long)
End Sub

Sub Activity_Create(FirstTime As Boolean)
    b1.Initialize("Set100")
    b1.Text="Set100"
    Activity.AddView(b1,10%x,10%y,80%x,20%y)
    b2.Initialize("SetBig")
    b2.Text="SetBig"
    Activity.AddView(b2,10%x,40%y,80%x,20%y)
    b3.Initialize("Increase")
    b3.Text="long++"
    Activity.AddView(b3,10%x,70%y,80%x,20%y)
    MapData.Initialize
End Sub

Sub Activity_Resume

End Sub

Sub Activity_Pause (UserClosed As Boolean)

End Sub

Sub Set100_Click
    Dim l As Long
    l = 100
    Log("set to: " & l)
    MapData.Put("Token",l)

End Sub

Sub SetBig_Click
    ' long range: -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807
    Dim l As MyLong
    l.l = 640345893847300380
    Log("set to: " & l)
    MapData.Put("Token",l)
End Sub

Sub Increase_Click
    Log(MapData.Get("Token"))
    Dim l As MyLong
    l = MapData.Get("Token")
    l.l = l.l + 1
    'If you want to create a copy of the original MyLong object:
    Dim l2 As MyLong
    l2.l = l.l
    Log("new val : " & l.l)
    MapData.Put("Token",l2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Any idea how i can get the long number from a String variable?

Comment: You can use [BigNumbers](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/help/bignumbers.html) for that.